# How to get AngleProperty

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I can apply **angle** like

```
double angle = 30;
Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
r.Width = 5;
r.Height = 130;
r.Fill = Brushes.Black;
r.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform(angle);
canvas1.Children.Add(r);
```

but I am not sure how to get back  **angle** value?

Comment: why are you creating UI elements in code to begin with?

Comment: @HighCore I need it. :)

Comment: @HighCore That has nothing to do with the question, and there is nothing wrong with creating UI elements in code.

Comment: @FlyingStreudel Unless this is some kind of `Custom Control` (not UserControl) this is a terribly bad approach. This is not winforms, it's WPF, and in WPF there is XAML, which is what you create your UI with. Even if the intent is to show multiple objects in a control, that can be done with an `ItemsControl` and some DataTemplates. That's the WPF way of doing things.

Comment: @HighCore Terribly bad is subjective. For instance XAML becomes quite a headache when working with data that is not normalized.

Comment: @FlyingStreudel That's what a ViewModel is for. and XAML is never a headache if you have the right mindset.

Comment: @HighCore Like I said, its purely subjective. If you like the MVVM design pattern, and you don't mind adding a dependency on PRISM or a similar framework then go for it.

Comment: @FlyingStreudel PRISM What?? I prefer doing things the RIGHT way, not the dinosaur-winforms-dont-try-to-scale-it-a-little-bit-because-you-will-need-to-refactor-everything way.

Comment: @FlyingStreudel Obviously you have no idea what you're talking about. We have a BIG LOB in WPF making extensive use of MVVM concepts and NEVER needed prism or anything else.

Comment: @HighCore Sir, you need to settle down. I'm not attacking you or your preferred method of development. A blanket statement saying that declaring UI elements in code is somehow wrong or prehistoric is not telling the whole story. There are times when it will take 500 lines of XAML in three files and 2 supporting classes to make a change that could be done with 100 lines of C# in one file. The decision on which path to choose should be made on cost to develop and maintain, not blind adherence to a design pattern. If you would still like to discuss this lets chat not clutter the comments further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may save the rotate transform and access it later;

```
RotateTransform rTransform = new RotateTransform(angle);
...
var temp = rTransform.Angle;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may always try to cast an element's `RenderTransform` to a `RotateTransform` and (in case of a  successful cast) get the angle value from the `Angle` property:

```
var element = canvas1.Children[0];
var transform = element.RenderTransform as RotateTransform;
var angle = transform != null ? transform.Angle : 0.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Transforms are 3x3 matrices. You can read about the rotation specific bit [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix)

You can access the matrix by using the `RenderTransform.Value` property (not by plugging a cord into the back of your head as previously theorized)

Use the `Matrix.M11`, `Matrix.M12`, `Matrix.M21` and `Matrix.M22` values to compute your angle!